# AWK print records to separate files by the column and replace that column with value when null

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to break a large file up by the first column value and when that column is null, replace the null with a value and still create a file from those bad records.
I tried something like

```
awk -F'|' '{print match($1,/^ /) > $1 : "BAD"} $FILENAME
```

but of course that doesn't work.

```
A|123|zxy
B|321|zyx
|345|abc
A|456|zys
```

Create 3 files: `A`, `B`, and `BAD`

Comment: what are you trying to do with the `match()` there?

Comment: I was trying to match a null value. I am using bash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F '|' '{ fname = $1 ? $1 : "BAD"; print >fname }' file
```

This sets the variable `fname` to the value of the first column if it exists, otherwise to `BAD`. The line is then printed to that filename.

If you have *a lot* af different values in the first column, then you may want to close the output files between each `print` statement as to not run out of file descriptors:

```
awk -F '|' '{ fname = $1 ? $1 : "BAD"; print >>fname; close fname }' file
```

Note that we now must open the file in append mode with `>>`.